# Get a view of a ndarray satisfying certain shape and strides constraint

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy ndarray, say `A`, whose data buffer is C-contiguous. Now I want to get a view of this matrix, with known offset, shape and strides, how can I do this?

For example, if I have:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.zeros((100, 100))
```

Suppose I would like to get a matrix `B` which is a view of `A`, whose offset is 880 bytes with respect to `A`, and with shape (10, 20) and strides (8, 800), I can do the following:

```
B = A[1:21, 10:20].T
```

Is there a method to get such a view matrix in the general case? I guess there are three possible approaches, any of them is good for me:

1. A general procedure to come up with a sequence of transformations like the above to construct the view matrix `B`?
2. Construct a ndarray with starting address, offset, shape, and strides manually specified?
3. I have the above four things in C++, so I could also call Python C API to construct such an ndarray.

Btw, I'm also wondering which attribute of `B` records its offset with respect to the start address of `A`?

Comment: look at the functions in `np.lib.stride_tricks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want full control over everything, you can use the [`np.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) constructor directly, and do something like:

```
B = np.ndarray(shape=(10, 20), dtype=A.dtype, buffer=A, offset=880,
               strides=(8, 800))
```

Comment: Will that copy the contents of the buffer or will it reuse it?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [53]: A.__array_interface__
Out[53]: 
{'data': (173143872, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'shape': (100, 100),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3}

In [54]: B.__array_interface__
Out[54]: 
{'data': (173144752, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'shape': (10, 20),
 'strides': (8, 800),
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3}
```

The difference between the `data` pointer values is 880.

Comment: Interesting! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the useful solutions. What I end up doing is actually calling [`PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData) and then modify the strides in-place using [`PyArray_STRIDES`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_STRIDES). I could call [`PyArray_New`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_New) to setup all the parameter on calling, but I don't know how to set the flags, etc.